# make the TeX xtable results well formatted and easier to read

Tags: r, xtable

Is there a way to make the TeX xtable source code results well formatted and easier to read. Example:

```
library(xtable)
## Load example dataset
data(tli)
print(tli.table)
```

gives

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrlllr}
  \hline
 & grade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\ 
  \hline
1 & 6 & M & YES & HISPANIC & 43 \\ 
  2 & 7.0 & M & NO & BLACK & 88.0 \\ 
  3 & 5.00 & F & YES & HISPANIC & 34.00 \\ 
  4 & 3.000 & M & YES & HISPANIC & 65.000 \\ 
  5 & 8.0000 & M & YES & WHITE & 75.0000 \\ 
  6 & 5 & M & NO & BLACK & 74 \\ 
  7 & 8.0 & F & YES & HISPANIC & 72.0 \\ 
  8 & 4.00 & M & YES & BLACK & 79.00 \\ 
  9 & 6.000 & M & NO & WHITE & 88.000 \\ 
  10 & 7.0000 & M & YES & HISPANIC & 87.0000 \\ 
  11 & 3 & M & NO & WHITE & 79 \\ 
  12 & 6.0 & F & NO & WHITE & 84.0 \\ 
  13 & 8.00 & M & NO & WHITE & 90.00 \\ 
  14 & 5.000 & M & NO & WHITE & 73.000 \\ 
  15 & 8.0000 & F & NO & WHITE & 72.0000 \\ 
  16 & 6 & F & NO & BLACK & 82 \\ 
  17 & 4.0 & M & NO & WHITE & 69.0 \\ 
  18 & 3.00 & F & YES & HISPANIC & 17.00 \\ 
  19 & 3.000 & M & NO & HISPANIC & 37.000 \\ 
  20 & 5.0000 & M & NO & WHITE & 70.0000 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If I use something like http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ it gives the following (much equally spaced columns and hence more readable in TeX)

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrlllr}
    \hline
           & grade  & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth  \\ \hline
        1  & 6      & M   & YES     & HISPANIC & 43      \\
        2  & 7.0    & M   & NO      & BLACK    & 88.0    \\
        3  & 5.00   & F   & YES     & HISPANIC & 34.00   \\
        4  & 3.000  & M   & YES     & HISPANIC & 65.000  \\
        5  & 8.0000 & M   & YES     & WHITE    & 75.0000 \\
        6  & 5      & M   & NO      & BLACK    & 74      \\
        7  & 8.0    & F   & YES     & HISPANIC & 72.0    \\
        8  & 4.00   & M   & YES     & BLACK    & 79.00   \\
        9  & 6.000  & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 88.000  \\
        10 & 7.0000 & M   & YES     & HISPANIC & 87.0000 \\
        11 & 3      & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 79      \\
        12 & 6.0    & F   & NO      & WHITE    & 84.0    \\
        13 & 8.00   & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 90.00   \\
        14 & 5.000  & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 73.000  \\
        15 & 8.0000 & F   & NO      & WHITE    & 72.0000 \\
        16 & 6      & F   & NO      & BLACK    & 82      \\
        17 & 4.0    & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 69.0    \\
        18 & 3.00   & F   & YES     & HISPANIC & 17.00   \\
        19 & 3.000  & M   & NO      & HISPANIC & 37.000  \\
        20 & 5.0000 & M   & NO      & WHITE    & 70.0000 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

thanks

Comment: I gather you are referring to legibility of *source code* and not that of typeset output?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Courvoisier - Your text editor should provide such a feature.  If you use Emacs, try `M-x align-current RET`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the input material in the `tabular` environment isn't too illegible, I would put in next to no effort at all to pretty-print the input material. In contrast, I would exert considerable effort to make the typeset *output* more visually appealing to your readers, say along the following lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\scshape}l}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} T{2.0} T{1.4} LLL T{2.4} @{}}
  \toprule
  & {\scshape grade} & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & {\scshape tlimth} \\
  \midrule
  1 & 6 & m & yes & hispanic & 43 \\
  2 & 7.0 & m & no & black & 88.0 \\
  3 & 5.00 & f & yes & hispanic & 34.00 \\
  4 & 3.000 & m & yes & hispanic & 65.000 \\
  5 & 8.0000 & m & yes & white & 75.0000 \\
  6 & 5 & m & no & black & 74 \\
  7 & 8.0 & f & yes & hispanic & 72.0 \\
  8 & 4.00 & m & yes & black & 79.00 \\
  9 & 6.000 & m & no & white & 88.000 \\
  10 & 7.0000 & m & yes & hispanic & 87.0000 \\
  11 & 3 & m & no & white & 79 \\
  12 & 6.0 & f & no & white & 84.0 \\
  13 & 8.00 & m & no & white & 90.00 \\
  14 & 5.000 & m & no & white & 73.000 \\
  15 & 8.0000 & f & no & white & 72.0000 \\
  16 & 6 & f & no & black & 82 \\
  17 & 4.0 & m & no & white & 69.0 \\
  18 & 3.00 & f & yes & hispanic & 17.00 \\
  19 & 3.000 & m & no & hispanic & 37.000 \\
  20 & 5.0000 & m & no & white & 70.0000 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```